# Взлом wpa2 wifi при помощи видеокарты

Tags: gpu, безопасность, wifi

Здравствуйте. подскажите пожалуйста,как взломать пароль wpa2 при помощи видеокарты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте Hashcat.
Есть ещё EWSA

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю